# IdentityServer4 and Middleware

Tags: identityserver4, middleware

We have Resource API protected IdentityServer, On this We want to Add a Middleware, that will check the incoming request and will do some processing on it.
But we want this processing logic to get executed only for Authorized requests.
Please do let me know Where we can add this middleware and how I can confirm the request is authenticated.
We want the middleware to be added before MVC

Answer (score 0):

Add the middleware after the `UseAuthentication` and before `UseMvc`. You will be able to inspect the context in your new middleware to see if it is authenticated or not.

Comment: Thanks for rely,, I am short of aware of this comment, but not exactly getting how to check for authentication of clientcrendetials
as I think context.user.Isauthentication will always return false as there is no user involve in clientcredential.

Comment: @Shaj I don't know about `IsAuthenticated` property on the user but the `ClaimsPrincipal` is definitely created even in `ClientCredentials` flow. I've got this line of code running in production  middleware to do similar thing. `HttpContext.User.Claims.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Type == "clientid")?.Value` so you should be able to do something like that to get the data that you need for your business logic.